# Creating action for Idea plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, action

It's my first experience with creating Idea plugin, so I decided to read some manuals. They say it's required to create an action class. But "OK" button is disabled. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your answers.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Class Name` should not contain a package.